# JQuery rails: $getScript not even sending a request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm a complete jquery newbie, but I'm following [this tutorial here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) to get me started.

I had it all working already, but (and I don't even know what I did) now everything is just going down...

Here's the snippet (see comments):

```
$( function() {

  //This one here works and gets executed after the page has loaded
  $.getScript( "some link copied from one of the actual hrefs" );

  //Handler for some links that should load some js from the server and execute it
  $( '#searchresults .pagination a' ).live( 'click',
        function( event ) {
          //This shows the correct link:
          alert( this.href );

          //However, this one doesn't even send a request:
          $.getScript( this.href );

          return false;
        } );
} );
```

I'm using JQuery 1.5.2.

Also worth noting: I've installed FireQuery for debugging purposes, and it just keeps bombarding me with "`jQuery(...) called incorrectly`" everytime I load the site. When I click one of the links, it gives me "`When I called jQuery.get(...) with your args, an error was thrown! TypeError: rootjQuery is undefined`".

After seeing that I thought that my jquery.js file may be corrupt so I freshly downloaded and installed it. No luck there, though...

any help appreciated, thx

Comment: Try hardcoding the url into the $.getScript( paste the alert url here ); and see if the URL is a valid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... I had installed FireQuery to make debugging easier. Turns out it corrupted the actual jquery script.

Removed it and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you trying to getScript() from a different domain? i.e. the Rails app is running on http://www.foo.com/ and you are trying to getScript("http://www.bar.com/...")? You should not be able to make an Ajax request cross-domain.

It sounds a lot like the getScript() is failing.

Comment: nope, all of the files are on my local machine, and thus all accessed via localhost atm

Comment: Did you try hardcoding the path, as @nolabel recommended?